# Activity monitoring flow charts using php and mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When i upload .csv file to database, I need to make activity monitoring flow charts looks below.

Expected output sample:
[image]

I have done something here but i get output looks below.

My output:
[image]

Every connecting line indicates activities like cable laying, Camera mounting like that.

what is the simplest way to get exact output? Anyone give me an idea or sample codes to proceed further.

Any samples are there?

My sample database:
[image]

My php code

```
  <div>          
        <?php
        $start = "SELECT * FROM plot_points where sub='strat'";
        $query0 = mssql_query($start);
        $row0 = mssql_fetch_array($query0);
        if ($query0 > 0 && $row0['postion'] == '0') {
            ?>
            <!--                <div class="start">
                                <img  src="img/tri.jpg" alt="" style="float: left;" />
                                   <div class="" id="progressbar1"  style=" float: left;width:100px; padding-top: 15px; margin-left: -15px;   "></div>                       
                            </div>-->


            <?php
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM plot_points ";
        $query = mssql_query($sql);
        echo '<div class="start">';
        $i = 1;
        $top = 0;
        $ml = 70;


        while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)) {
            if ($row['sub'] == 'strat') {
                ?>
                <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px; margin-top: -20px;"><?php echo $row['points']; ?></span>

                <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/start.png" alt="" style="float: left; height: 50px; width:50px;" />

                <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; padding-top: 20px;   margin-left: 0px;   "></div>                       
                <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px;margin-top:10px;   margin-left: -100px;   "></div>  
                <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; margin-top:30px;   margin-left: -100px;   "></div>  
                <?php
            } else {
                if ($row['postion'] == '0' && $row['sub'] != 'strat') {
                    ?>  

                    <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px; top:-7px; margin-left: 8px;"><?php echo $row['points']; ?></span>
                    <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/tri.jpg" alt="" style="float: left;" />
                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; padding-top: 15px; margin-left: -15px;   "></div> 

                    <?php
                } elseif ($row['postion'] == '90') {
                    $mtop = '-120px';
                    ?>
                   <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px;  margin-left:-140px; margin-top:-90px;"><?php echo $row['points']; ?></span>
                    <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/tri.jpg" alt="" style="float: left; margin-left:-140px; margin-top:-90px;" />
                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:50px; transform: rotate(90deg); margin-left:-155px;  margin-top:-35px; ; ">fdg</div> 

                    <?php
                    $q = mssql_query("SELECT *  FROM  plot_points WHERE  sub ='" . $row['points'] . "'");
                    $sstop = 90;
                    $t = 1;
                    $top1 = 0;
                    while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_array($q)) {
                        // echo $row1['postion'];
                        if ($row1['postion'] == '90') {

                            $mttop = $sstop + 90;
                            $ttp = '-' . $mttop . 'px';
                            $ttp5 = '-' . $mttop + 50 . 'px';
                            $left = 140;
                            $le = '-' . $left . 'px';
                            $ttptop = '-' . $mttop-10 . 'px';
                            $sstop = $mttop;
                            ?>
                            <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px;margin-left:<?php echo $le; ?>; margin-top:<?php echo $ttptop; ?> ;"><?php echo $row1['next_points']; ?></span>

                            <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/<?php echo $row1['icons'] ?>" alt="" style="float: left; margin-left:<?php echo $le; ?>; margin-top:<?php echo $ttp; ?> ;" />
                            <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:50px; transform: rotate(90deg); margin-left:-155px;  margin-top:<?php echo $ttp5; ?> ; "></div> 


                        <?php } elseif ($row1['postion'] == '180') { ?>
                            <?php
                            $q1 = mssql_query("SELECT *  FROM  plot_points WHERE  points ='" . $row1['points'] . "'");

                            while ($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($q1)) {
                                $mttop1 = $top1 + 90;
                                $ttp1 = '-' . $mttop1 . 'px';
                                $ttp2 = '-' . $mttop1 - 10 . 'px';
                                $ttp3 = '-' . $mttop1 - 20 . 'px';
                                $ttpb = '-' . $mttop1-10 . 'px';
                                if ($row2['postion'] == '180') {
                                    ?>
                              <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px;margin-left:-290px; margin-top:<?php echo $ttpb; ?> ;"><?php echo $row2['next_points']; ?></span>

                                    <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/<?php echo $row2['icons'] ?>" alt="" style="float: left; margin-left:-270px; margin-top:<?php echo $ttp1; ?> ;" />
                                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; transform: rotate(180deg); margin-left:-230px;  margin-top:<?php echo $ttp1; ?> ; "></div> 
                                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; transform: rotate(180deg); margin-left:-230px;  margin-top:<?php echo $ttp2; ?> ; "></div> 
                                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:100px; transform: rotate(180deg); margin-left:-230px;  margin-top:<?php echo $ttp3; ?> ; "></div> 
                                <?php } else { ?>

                                <?php }
                                ?>


                            <?php }$top1 = 90;
                            ?>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php
                        $top += 90;

                        $t++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                } elseif ($row['postion'] == '270') {
                    $mtop = '90px';
                    ?>
                    <img id="<?php echo $row['points']; ?><?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" src="img/<?php echo $row['icons'] ?>" alt="" style="float: left; margin-left:-140px;margin-top:<?php echo $mtop; ?> " />
                    <div class="progressbar<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"  style=" float: left;width:57px; transform: rotate(270deg); margin-left:-125px;  margin-top:45px; ; "></div> 
                    <span style=" position: fixed; font-size: 13px;margin-left:-140px;margin-top:130px; "><?php echo $row['next_points']; ?></span>
                        <?php
                } elseif ($row['postion'] == '180') {
                    //echo 'vbn';
                }
                ?>

            <?php }
            ?>

            <?php
            $i++;
        }
        echo ' </div> ';
        ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: without any sample DB data we cannot easily see what the issue might be

Comment: Wait. i will attach sample @ADyson

Comment: actual data as text, not pictures please. Otherwise no-one can easily re-use it to test your code. We don't want to have to type it all out again. Thanks.